# IPOPT error: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, scipy, nonlinear-optimization, ipopt

Good morning,

I am trying to run a non-linear optimization problem by using IPOPT solver in python. However, when I run it, displays the following error:  only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars.

I tried changing in the minimize_ipopt function objective_function --> objective function (x) but that worked even worse --> it just exited my python.

This is the code I am running:

```html
df_sku_demand_stockout = pd.DataFrame(c.fetchall(), columns = ['sku', 'demand_rate', 'prob_stockout'])

#Define the parameters
nr_sku = df_sku_demand_stockout.shape[0]
s = df_sku_demand_stockout['demand_rate'].astype('float').tolist()
sigma = df_sku_demand_stockout['prob_stockout'].astype('float').tolist()

#Define x
x = pd.DataFrame(index=range(nr_sku),columns=range(nr_sku+2))
x1 = x

#now we transform the dataframe in a vector --> needed to be input in the model
#x = x.values.astype('float').tolist()
x = x.to_numpy().flatten()
i = 0
j = 0

aux = x.reshape(nr_sku, (nr_sku+2))
sub_rate = aux[:, :nr_sku]
intrinsic_demand = aux[:, nr_sku].reshape(nr_sku,1)
s_est = aux[:, (nr_sku +1)].reshape(nr_sku,1)

#Define the objective function
def objective_function(x):
    #sub_rate = pd.DataFrame(x).iloc[:, : nr_sku].astype('int64').to_numpy()
    #intrinsic_demand = pd.DataFrame(x).iloc[:, nr_sku].astype('int64').to_numpy()
    #s_est = pd.DataFrame(x).iloc[:, (nr_sku + 1)].astype('int64').to_numpy()
    e = 0
    x = x.reshape(nr_sku, (nr_sku+2 ))
    for i in range(nr_sku):
        for j in range(nr_sku):
            if i == j:
                s_est[i] = intrinsic_demand[i]
            else:
                s_est[i] = intrinsic_demand[i] + sub_rate[j,i] * intrinsic_demand[j] * sigma[j]
    
    for i in range(nr_sku):
        for j in range((nr_sku+2)):
            if j<nr_sku:
                x[i,j] = sub_rate[i,j]
            elif j == nr_sku:
                x[i,j] = intrinsic_demand[i]
            elif j == (nr_sku + 1):
                x[i,j] = s_est[i]
    x = x.flatten()

    for i in range(nr_sku):
        e += (s[i] - s_est[i])**2

    #x = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(sub_rate),pd.DataFrame(intrinsic_demand)], axis = 1)
    #x = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x), pd.DataFrame(s_est)], axis = 1)
    return e
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.optimize import LinearConstraint
from scipy.optimize import Bounds


# Define the constraints
def constraint_fun_1(x):
    aux1 = x.reshape(nr_sku, (nr_sku+2))
    sub_rate = aux1[:, :nr_sku]
    aux2 = sub_rate.sum(axis=1)
    return aux2 - 1

bounds = [[0, None] for i in range(len(x))]
obj_jit = jit(objective_function)
con_eq_jit = jit(constraint_fun_1)


cons = [
    {'type': 'eq', 'fun': con_eq_jit}]

# Define the initial guess
x0 = x1.fillna(0)
x0 = x0.to_numpy().flatten()
# Run optimization
res = minimize_ipopt(
    objective_function,
    jac = None,
    hess= None,
    x0 = x0,
    bounds = bounds,
    constraints=cons,
    options={
    }
)


# Extract results
print(res)
```

If anyone can help!

Comment: Sounds like your objective function returns numpy array instead of a scalar value. Btw, your code snippet isn't a [minimal **reproducible** example](Sounds like your objective function returns numpy array instead of a scalar value. Btw, your code snippet isn't a [minimal **reproducible** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as it depends on some missing dataframes.

Comment: But the idea is that the algorithm should be able to compute e as the sum of all errors across the dataframes, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show the actual error(s) - with full traceback.  If you can't provide enough diagnostic information, then at least provide a [mcve] that we can run - with a simple copy-n-paste.  You import `minimize` but use `minimize_ipopt`; more posters will be familiar with the `scipy` function than with the `ipopt` version.

Comment: I suggest to use IPOPT from Pyomo. That gives you automatic differentiation, so IPOPT won't need to do finite differences.